# parsing XML and count and sum the "counts", why "counts = tree.findall('comment/coment')" generate []

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


url = raw_input('Enter location: ')

print 'Retrieving', url
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
print data
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
tree = ET.fromstring(data)

counts = tree.findall('comment/comment')
print counts
```

the XML data format:

```
<comment>
  <name>Matthias</name>
  <count>97</count> 
</comment>
```

Comment: the XML data format is like

Comment: the XML data format:<comment>
  <name>Matthias</name>
  <count>97</count>
</comment>

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
counts = tree.findall('.//comment')
```

This will retrieve all the sub-trees containing 'name' and 'count'. To find all the values in the 'count' tag, just use a for loop:

```
for values in counts:
    print int(values.find('count').text)
```

You can get the sum from there.

Answer (score 0):

According to the XML you've provided, `comment/comment` matches nothing.

You've probably meant to use:

```
tree.findall('.//comment/count')
```

Then, if you want to sum the counts:

```
sum(int(c.text) for c in tree.findall('.//comment/count'))
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it shows a syntax error, say "cannot use

Comment: it says can not use absolute path on elelment

Comment: @user5584054 are you sure you have a dot at the beginning of an xpath?

Comment: sorry, my bad, It actually worked out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: well, one more question for you, the command tree.findall('.//comment/count') did not generate a list, kind of confusing. can you explain?

Comment: I mean it did generate a list, but not the list I expected.

Comment: @user5584054 the list of `Element` instances is returned - this is why I'm looping over it and calling `.text` on each item. You can get the texts directly via `.//comment/count/text()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum with below code in python3:

```
counts = tree.findall('.//count')

total =0

for item in counts:

    total +=int(item.text)

print("Sum :",total)
```